# ArcGIS Pro - Voxel layer doesn't show even though all coordinate systems match

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, netcdf, wgs84, voxel

I created a NetCDF file and then added it as a multidimensional voxel layer to ArcGIS Pro. I then got this warning:

> Voxel layer can only be drawn in local scenes with the same coordinate system as the voxel layer. Change the scene to a local scene and the coordinate system of the scene to match the voxel layer.

Looking at the scene's Map Properties > Coordinate Systems, I found that my voxel layer used the `WGS 1984` coordinate system while the World Topographic Map and WorldElevation3D/Terrain3D layers used the `WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)` coordinate system.

I found [this FAQ](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/voxel-layer-freqently-asked-questions.htm#anchor5) that suggets using a projection file to override the coordinate system of the NetCDF file used for the voxel layer. I did it successfully, and got my voxel layer, AIRS_Voxel, to use the `WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)` coordinate system.

[image]

However, I'm still getting the same warning about the coordinate systems not matching. I've also tried changing the Z coordinate system to both `None` and `WGS 1984`, to no effect. I've also restarted ArcGIS Pro, to no effect.

Here's the spatial reference for my voxel layer, in case it helps:

[image]

What should I do?

EDIT: The warning about coordinate systems not matching is no longer showing. However, the voxel layer still won't display.

Comment: Voxel layers can only display regularly gridded data. There is a note in the [voxel FAQ](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/layer-properties/voxel-layer-freqently-asked-questions.htm#anchor15). Could this be the cause of your display problem?

Comment: @MarkBryant This indeed turned out to be the issue, along with needing my region to be at least 33x33 degrees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to my issue with the help of Esri's support ([Andrew--Johnson of Esri](https://community.esri.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/147844)). (our discussion on this matter is available [here](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/voxel-layer-doesn-t-show-even-though-all/m-p/1313832)).

There were two issues that led to the voxel layer not displaying:

- The z-dimension was not regularly gridded
- The geographic region of my data was small